# How to inject values of one dataset to another dataset in jasper

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports

I have two data-sets having count of products from one table,and another data-set having sun(prices of product) from a different table.I have two separate data-sets for these two queries.Now I need to use the values of these two data-sets in the third row in my report as SUM/count.How do I inject those two fields into my third data-set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using JOIN.I used join between two select statements.

```
SELECT products.count,prices.sumofproducts FROM
(select count(*) as count,1 as DUMMY from products) products
join
(select sum(prices) as sumofproducts,1 as DUMMY from prices) prices
on products.DUMMY=prices.DUMMY
```